# How often do you emit state in a MV* reactive architecture?

Tags: android, reactive-programming

The root of this question was simple. The application is a game and one of its feature is a timer. In my initial design, Im including the current time of the timer to the state so the view can render it. As an obvious effect, I'm emitting a new state at least once every second with the current time of the timer as the only change.

1. I that okay? Should I not worry about creating new state at least once every second?
2. Or should I change this design and put the timer in a separate stream?

Comment: Seems like that'd depend on the nature of the state. Once a second isn't particularly often (e.g., think of a stopwatch w/ thousandths resolution, that's updated every ms). If the state is complex or expensive to compute then you might want it separately--just depends.

Comment: Yeah, I guess thats it. Thanks @DaveNewton!